# Remove from one file what is in another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, grep

I have two text files, file1.txt and file2.txt.

file1.txt contains a list of numbers. file2.txt also contains a list of numbers, but more of them (a good chunk are numbers from file1.txt). This is what I am trying to do:

I want to remove all the numbers in file1.txt from file2.txt and have the output saved to file3.txt. So in file3.txt, it will contain no numbers from file1.txt. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

This reads file1 into an array, then when iterating through file2, it will print lines of file2 that are not in the array and write them to an output file. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. Cheers.

Comment: Time: 1.010 seconds for file1.txt with 10k and file2.txt with 1M numbers.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `grep`, you can use the '`fgrep`' mode:

```
grep -F -v -f file1.txt -w file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Demo:

```
seq 1 30 > file2.txt
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $RANDOM; done | sed 's/\(..\).*/\1/' > file1.txt
grep -F -v -f file1.txt -w file2.txt > file3.txt
```

The contents of `file2.txt` is lines with numbers 1 through 30.  The content of `file1.txt` is 5 semi-random 2-digit numbers.  The output in `file3.txt` is the lines in file 2 that are not in file 1.  Note that the random number generated by the loop are not very good, nor constrained to 1..30 (see also comments just below).

The feature that is specific to GNU `grep` is the `-w` flag, which matches whole words.  Interestingly, POSIX 2008 specifies that `-x` should match exact lines, and the `-x` option works correctly for me (on Mac OS X 10.7.5, but `/usr/bin/grep` is GNU grep 2.5.1).  In theory, the `-x` is more portable.  Since it was in the [POSIX 1997](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/grep.html) standard too, it should be widely available.  The `-w` option would be more appropriate if there were multiple numbers on a single line (but `grep` would eliminate whole lines).

Comment: +1. According to the OP's question file1.txt and file2.txt should be swapped. Btw. you could get more controlled randomizing with shuf: `seq 1 30 | shuf | head -n5`.

Comment: I'd not come across `shuf` (though I find it on my machine in my `/usr/gnu/bin` directory).  I have my own `random` to generate numbers (`random -n 5 1 30`), but I have to explain that.  Yes, it looks like I do have the roles of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` reversed compared to the question; there's slightly odd phraseology in the question and I misread it, so I'll fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree the question should be improved. `shuf` was added to GNU coreutils in August 2006, as such it's not as portable as using `$RANDOM`.

Comment: You could also use $(($RANDOM % 30 +1)) to keep the numbers within the limits of 1 and 30.

Comment: Time: 1.177 seconds for file1.txt with 10k and file2.txt with 1M numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort file1.txt file2.txt|uniq -u > file3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and got "sort: string comparison failed: Illegal byte sequence"

Comment: Maybe try exporting LC_ALL=C? So:

LC_ALL=C sort file1.txt file2.txt|uniq -u > file3.txt

Comment: If file1.txt is a subset of file2.txt, and file2.txt doesn't contain duplicates not found in file1.txt, this operation yields the difference.

Comment: For example, "echo -e 'foo\nbaz' > file1.txt; echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz' > file2.txt; sort file1.txt file2.txt|uniq -u > file3.txt" yields "bar".

Comment: I missed the significance of the `-u` option to `uniq`.  We live, we learn.

Comment: Time: 2.776 seconds for file1.txt with 10k and file2.txt with 1M numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unix "diff" command for get the difference and filter out unwanted lines. You can use **--changed-group-format** and **--unchanged-group-format** options to filter required data.

Following three options can use to select the relevant group for each option:

- '%<' get lines from FILE1
- '%>' get lines from FILE2
- '' (empty string) for removing lines from both files.

e.g:

```
diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format="" file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: There seems to be an error. I get a different file3.txt then with all other answers to this question, after sorting and removing non tabs which were inserted with comm (see Thor). And your answer is the slowest: 7.381 seconds for file1.txt with 10k and file2.txt with 1M numbers.

Comment: @erik good to know about the performance. thanks. What is the error you are talking about? did you try to compare two small files and check whether this gives the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You want to only print unique elements of file2.txt. This is what the `comm` utility is designed for:

```
comm -13 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

*Testing*

```
$ cat file1.txt
5
4
6
2
10

$ cat file2.txt
3
7
8
2
4
1
9
10
5
6

$ comm -13 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
1
3
7
8
9
```

Comment: Time: 2.170 seconds for file1.txt with 10k and file2.txt with 1M numbers. It is slower than awk although comm is designed for this kind of exercise?

Comment: Should the command be `comm -13 ...` so that if there are numbers in `file1.txt` that do not appear in `file2.txt`, they will not appear in the output?  What you've got is fine if every number in `file1.txt1` does appear somewhere in `file2.txt`.

Comment: @erik: was this with pre-sorted input?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you're right `-13` is more correct, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more information about how these numbers are formatted? Are each of them on a new line? Are they all the same number of digits?

EDIT: After receiving comment:

```
while read line
do
    bool="false"
    while read secLine
    do
        if [ "$line" == "$secLine" ]
        then
            bool="true"
        fi
    done <file1
    if [ "$bool" == "false" ]
    then
         echo $line >> file3.txt
    fi
done <file2
```

That will work, albeit by brute force (or it should work. Check for syntax errors. I didn't see any but there may be some.) It may take awhile depending on how many numbers you have.

Comment: They are a new line, and they aren't the same number of digits

Comment: I would suggest using a script to do this for you. Say, a script that checked each line file2 and compared it to each line in file1. If there was never a match,then put that specific line in file3.

Comment: There, there's a script that will work for you, I'm sure (as long as I didn't make any syntax errors)
Be warned, it may take awhile depending on the file sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think the file may be too large as I am receiving "line 6: [: too many arguments"

Comment: Ah, no actually, that's one of those elusive syntax errors I was afraid of >< put quotes around $line and $secLine and that should fix the problem.